# In Oracle PL/SQL can I swap the value of the same column of two differents rows in a table when the rest of the values of the columns are equal?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Basically I was mistaken when assigning values to some rows.  Two rows have the same values in all columns but one, and in that column the values should be swapped. How can I approach the issue?

I have already tried with some code but it only works when one of the other values is different in order to use it as a reference. But when all the other values are the same it won't work.

In the 'bar' column I would just like to swap values from both rows.

`foo  bar  foo2`
`1    2    4`
`1    3    4`

Comment: If all the other values are the same, what's the issue? Here you have one row with value (1, 2, 4) and another with the values (1, 3, 4). Even if you *do* swap the 2 and 3 between rows, you still have two rows with values (1, 2, 4) and (1, 3, 4). In other words, there's no difference. Perhaps more to the point - what is the primary key on this table? If PK=(foo, bar, foo2) then you should not change the value of bar, because a primary key is 1. Never NULL, 2. Unique, and 3. Unchanging. Many people forget or conveniently ignore the last limitation, but - well, there you are.

Comment: The issue is if I am able to swap values, it is just an example there may be some other columns with different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a CASE statement:

```
update the_table
   set the_column = case pk_column
                      when 1 then (select the_column from the_table where pk_column = 2)
                      when 2 then (select the_column from the_table where pk_column = 1)
                    end
where pk_column in (1,2);
```

The above assumes that `pk_column` is defined as unique.

Comment: Could I jus append after the where statement an 'and' clause to restrict which rows can be affected? Thanks in advance